# Differential Form of Gauss's Law for Cylinder

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Consider a conductive solid cylinder of radius $R$ and length $L$ having the charge $Q$. Considering a cylinder of radius $r>R$ with the same length as the Gaussian surface and assuming that we only have electrical field in the radial direction, the integral form of Gauss's law gives us
\begin{equation}\label{eq:0}
E = \dfrac{Q}{2\pi \epsilon L r}.
\end{equation}

Now, I want to get the electrical field using Gauss's law in the differential form
\begin{align}\label{eq:1}
\vec{\nabla}.\vec{E} = \dfrac{dE}{dr} = \dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon}
\end{align}
My problem is how to define the charge density $\rho$. Since all charges will be accumulated at the outermost surface, I considered
\begin{equation}
\rho (r) = \dfrac{Q}{2\pi RL}\delta(r-R)
\end{equation}
with $\delta(.)$ being the Dirac delta function. The volume integration of this density gives us the net charge:
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{L}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{r} \rho(s)sdsd\theta dz = Q.
\end{align}
However, when I try to solve the above differential equation, after integrating from $ 0 $ to $ r>R $, I get
\begin{align}
E(r) - E(0) = \dfrac{Q}{2\pi\epsilon RL}\int\limits_{0}^{r}\delta(s-R) ds= \dfrac{Q}{2\pi\epsilon RL},
\end{align}
which is not $r$-dependent. What is my mistake?

Comment: The differential formula gives the divergence of the field inside of a 3D charge distribution.

Comment: When you integrated in the last line , you put definite bounds in it, If you change the 'r' value  to a variable in the upper bound of it, then it'll recover original answer